# Transfer real-time data via UDP

Tags: c#, udp

I need to transfer some large data buffer via UDP(User Datagram protocol ). This buffer is divided into 1452 bytes datagrams. The first two bytes is the datagram number (++dtgrNr % 65536). The number is for  detection of lost datagrams. I'd like to control the bitrate as follows:
e.g., for 1 MBps the buffer length (bufferSize) is 100 kB, the timer function `SendBuffer` is called every 100ms.
for 2 MBps the buffer length is 200 kB and so on.

```
SendBuffer() // simplified version
{

int current_idx = 0;
while(current_idx < bufferSize)
{
  GetCounterBytes(counter, ref b1, ref b2);  // obtaining two bytes of datagram counter
  datagram[0] = b1;
  datagram[1] = b2;
  Array.Copy(buffer, current_idx, datagram, 2, datagramSize);

  try
  {
     int sentLen = udpClient.Send(datagram, datagram.Length);
     if(sentLen <= 0)
          Console.WriteLine("error");
  }
  catch .........

  current_idx += datagramSize;
}
```

The problem is with sending datagrams. It seems that some of these are not send.
Send method is called inside the loop and it may cause some timeout problem?
But sentLen value is always > 0 and no catch block is called.
Could you help me with the problem?
Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: If the sentLen is alsways >0 means that the packets are sent, but with udp protocol you are not sure that the packets are received, i suggest to analyze the problem with a network sniffer, for example WireShark

Comment: "It seems that some of these are not send" -- based on what evidence? You even wrote "The number is for detection of lost datagrams", so you do _seem_ to understand that UDP is unreliable; datagrams can be lost at any point along the way. You don't seem to be asking a question about something that is answerable or fixable.